# Calculate Random color with method parameters

Tags: c#, .net, random, colors, system.drawing

I have method, for generating random colors.
This method has 3 parameters and result color should be equal, if passed parameters are equal.
Please, help me to find formula (some expression) for calculate random color.

```
 protected static string RandomColor(int metaDataId, int operationId, int dataType)
        {
            var names = (KnownColor[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(KnownColor));

            metaDataId = Math.Abs(metaDataId); // metaDataId = {1...N}
            operationId = Math.Abs(operationId);// operationId = {1...N}
            dataType = Math.Abs(dataType);// dataType = {1..6}

            var colorsCount = names.Length;
            var seed = /* some operations for generating Random color */;
            var randomGen = new Random(seed);

            Color randomColor;
            while (true)
            {
                var randomColorName = names[randomGen.Next(names.Length)];
                randomColor = Color.FromKnownColor(randomColorName);
                var brightness = randomColor.GetBrightness();
                if (brightness < 0.7 && brightness > 0.2)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            return ColorTranslator.ToHtml(randomColor);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want a random color, but a deterministic (probably nonlinear) mapping from values to colors.  Rather than use random, why not use another algorithm to transform the values into a index, but in a nonlinear fashion.

```
protected static string RandomColor(int metaDataId, int operationId, int dataType)
{
    var names = (KnownColor[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(KnownColor));

    metaDataId = Math.Abs(metaDataId);
    operationId = Math.Abs(operationId);
    dataType = Math.Abs(dataType);

    // compute a hash of the 3 values modulo the number of colors
    unchecked
    {
        var index = (17 + metaDataId * 23 + operationId * 23 + dataType * 23) % names.Length;
    }

    Color color;
    while (true)
    {
        var colorName = names[index];
        color = Color.FromKnownColor(randomColorName);
        var brightness = randomColor.GetBrightness();
        if (brightness < 0.7 && brightness > 0.2)
        {
            break;
        }
        ++index;
    }
    return ColorTranslator.ToHtml(color);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

a color is basically made up of 4 bytes: red, green, blue, and alpha. if your 3 integer type parameters will never exceed byte.MaxValue then you can apply those 3 parameters for the red/green/blue bytes of a color respectively using [Color.FromRgb](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.color.fromrgb.aspx) for example.